# How to make nodejs websocket request/response synchronized

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2017

I have a problem of implementing the synchronized programming pattern in nodejs when it comes with websocket `ws.send(msg)` and `ws.on('message', ...)`. I depicted my requirements in the pseudo-code snippet below.

```
ws.on('message', (data) => {
    let msg = JSON.parse(data)
    if (msg.MsgType == 'DummyResponse') {
        // we got one response and we need to send it to the 
        // corresponding RequestID's getResponse() function
        requestMap.get(msg.RequestID).unblockingGetResponse(msg)
    }
}   

async ctx => {
    ctx.body = await ws.send({MsgType:'DummyRequest', RequestID: uuid()}).getResponse()
}
```

My nodejs package.json dependencis

```
"dependencies": {
    "koa": "^2.2.0",
    "koa-router": "^7.1.1",
    "uuid": "^3.0.1",
    "ws": "^3.0.0"
}
```

My question is how to implement this in es6/7 properly?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using this pattern:

```
let resolveMap = new Map()

ws.on('message', (data, flags) => {
     let response = JSON.parse(data) 
     resolveMap.get(response.requestId)(response)
     resolveMap.delete(response.requestId)
}

async function() {
    //...
    let response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolveMap.set(request.requestId, resolve)
        ws.send(request)
    }
}
```